# Pass function of function as parameter

Tags: python, python-3.x

I know how to pass a simple function as parameter to another function - but how do I pass "nested" functions? I'm trying to do something like this:

```
def do(func):
    print (func(6))

def a(x):
    return x*2

def b(x):
    return x*3

do(a(b))
```

Comment: `do(lambda x: a(b(x)))`

Comment: You’re looking for [function composition](https://mathieularose.com/function-composition-in-python/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using function composition approach:

```
def compose(f, g):
    return lambda x: f(g(x))

def do(func):
    print (func(6))

def a(x):
    return x*2

def b(x):
    return x*3

combinedAB = compose(a,b)
do(combinedAB)
```

Answer (score 1):

Well the main problem here is that `do(a(b))` will pass the function `b` in the `a` and result in a `TypeError`.

The main issue here is that whatever you pass to function `do` *has to be a callable* or else the `print(func(6))` statement will fail for the appropriate reasons (lack of a `__call__` method) so I don't think the way this is structured fits what you're trying to do.

As a solution you could either do what @Doorknob suggested (essentially pass in a callable) or consider returning function `b` from function `a` which will then be used in function `do`.

So, if you change function `a` as so:

```
def do(func):
    print (func(6))

def a(x):
    x = x * 2
    def b(y):
        return x * (y * 3)
    return b

do(a(2))
```

You'll get a nice result of `72`. Even though I'm not sure if this is strictly what you mean by "nested" functions.